# Cakephp 3: use of "$this->alias()" in "where" conditions

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

To avoid the `Column 'xxx' in where clause is ambiguous` error when making queries involving multiple tables sharing the same name for a given column, I now systematically include $this->alias() in where conditions, like this :

```
$table->find()->where([$table->alias() . '.field' => 'value']);
```

Is this considered a good practice?

For some reasons I ignore, doing so leads to an error when using `updateAll` instead of `find` for tables that contains an underscore. Example:

```
$table = TableRegistry::get('BlogPosts');
$table->updateAll(
    [$table->alias() . '.title' => 'new title'],
    [$table->alias() . '.id'    => 1]
);
```

will throw the error:
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'BlogPosts.id' in 'where clause'` for the prepared query `UPDATE blog_posts SET BlogPosts.title = :c0 WHERE BlogPosts.id = :c1`

Is this a cakephp 3 bug? Or is it me who is misusing `$table->alias()`?

Comment: Does seem like a bug. The resulting query of updateAll() does not alias the table at all. It should output `UPDATE blog_posts AS BlogPosts SET...`. I would create an issue for this on their [github issue tracker](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues).

Comment: Well, all the issues I ever opened so far resulted in the conclusion that I missued cakephp :) . So now I prefer asking in stackoverflow before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not alias the conditions for `updateAll`. The reason is that only one table is involved in that method, so the alias is not required

Comment: Ok I see. I guess it's the same for `deleteAll`? Are there other methods for which adding an alias to conditions **must** be avoided?